# Show that C(n) = {a^k | k is a multiple of n} is a regular language

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, proof-techniques

I came across this question in an exam book and was unable to find a solution:

Prove that C(n) = {a^k | k is a multiple of n} is a regular language for every natural number n ≥ 1.

I wasn't able to construct a DFA as the number n is left variable in the original question. Is it possible to construct a DFA with a variable number of states?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: "Is it possible to construct a DFA with a variable number of states?" No, but you don't have to do that. All need to do is give a method (an algorithm, if you like) that can construct a DFA given an natural number $n$. I think that if you try to construct it for a few specific instances of $n$, you can figure out the general pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy to construct a DFA which recognize $a^n$.

Then add an $\epsilon$ transition from all its final state to its initial state.